# Excel COUNT() vs COUNTIF() with arrays

Tags: arrays, excel

I think this should be a straightforward question, but for some reason I can't find a solution anywhere.

I have a lengthy formula in excel that, ultimately, returns an array of four items -- i.e. {1,2,0,0}. I want to count how many of the resulting numbers are greater than zero.

When I use `=COUNT({1,2,0,0})` on this result, I get the expected answer of 4. But when I try to use `=COUNTIF({1,2,0,0}, ">0")` it pops up with an error saying that my formula has a problem.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there an array equivalent for COUNTIF() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the `COUNTIF` function only works on ranges, while the `COUNT` function can utilize an array.

Give `SUMPRODUCT` a try. Below is a slightly expanded form of your example which I used to test the formula. It basically checks to see if each value in the array is greater than 0, and if it is, it assigns it a value of 1. Then `SUMPRODUCT` goes through and adds up all the 1s to give you the total number of values greater than 0.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF({1,0,3,0,5,0,0,6,9,9,0,7,0}>0,1,0))
```

Comment: That seems to do it, thanks @tittaenälg - a clever way of getting around the problem. And why do you opt for `SUMPRODUCT` rather than simply a `SUM`, which I think would also work here? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @HAWK I knew `SUMPRODUCT` accepted arrays as input so I defaulted to that. You're right though, `SUM` looks like it gets the same results, so that seems equally correct and saves you some typing.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT is sometimes "better" than SUM because you may not need "array entry", depending on how you use SUMPRODUCT, but if your lengthy formula requires array entry anyway then SUM is probably preferable

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most concise way to accomplish this is to just convert the `TRUE` or `FALSE` value returned from the validation check into a number with the `INT` function. `TRUE` translates to `1` and `FALSE` translates to `0`. Then `SUM` those 1's and 0's.

```
=SUM(INT({1,2,0,0}>0))
```

Or as Barry Houdini points out, you can coerce the boolean to an int with:

```
=SUM(({1,2,0,0}>0)*1)
```

Or:

```
=SUM(({1,2,0,0}>0)+0)
```

Comment: In fact you don't even need a function like INT you can use a "co-ercer" like +0 or *1, e.g. `=SUM(({1,2,0,0}>0)+0)`

Comment: @barryhoudini Absolutely. I use the *1 method a lot. Using `INT` is actually atypical for me in cases like this so I'm not really sure why I did.